# How to hide Temporary tables in PgAdmin 4

Tags: database, postgresql, pgadmin-4

In our project we have a long list of Temporary schemas being created in the DB.

[image]

I have to scroll through the whole list of Temporary schemas and then reach the one on which I am working.
Deleting or removing the schema is not under my control.

I have tried the [documentation](https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin4/development/preferences.html) where it stated in Preference -> Browser -> Display -> Show system objects? switch is set to True, the client will display system objects such as system schemas (for example, pg_temp) or system columns (for example, xmin or ctid) in the tree control.

Thus I marked it as False but still I am able to see the list of Temporary tables.

[image]

Refreshed the connection also.

Is there any other way to hide the same? Or did I missed something?

Comment: If you hide the `pg_temp_X` schemas, how would you examine the temporary table with pgAdmin? Perhaps you should use a different client like `psql`.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I do agree with your suggestion but unfortunately I do not have the liberty to change the client being used.

Comment: I believe that if the feature were implemented and designed with foresight, that the hiding schemas wouldn't be done permanently, but only when desired, so examining them wouldn't be an issue.

Answer (score 0):

In the current version, you can look under

> Preferences > Browser > Display > Show system objects ?

The documentation says:

> When the Show system objects? switch is set to True, the client will
> display system objects such as system schemas (for example, pg_temp)
> or system columns (for example, xmin or ctid) in the tree control.

So this will hide them. However, if you want to hide only the temp schemas an nothing else, you could mess with the exposed `pgAdmin` object that's available in the browser as a global object.

I've created a hack implementation. Feel free to try this, but use it at your own risk, I accept no liability if you lose any data or code.

```
schemaQuery = window.prompt('Type a string to remove schemas containing this substring:')
function closetemp(ns){
    ns.forEach(n=>{
    if(n._metadata.data._type == 'coll-schema'){
      n._children.forEach(s=>{
        if(s._fileName.indexOf(schemaQuery)!=-1){
          pgAdmin.Browser.tree.remove(s)
        }
      })
    }
    if(n._children!=null){
        closetemp(n._children)
    }
  })
}
closetemp(pgAdmin.Browser.tree.children())
```

Run that in the browser console and a box will pop up. Type "_temp_" and it will remove every schema containing the string "_temp_" form the browser tree.

It crawls the tree, finds the schemas, and removes the nodes from the tree. It might cause errors I am unaware of, but if you refresh the tree from the menu the temp schemas (or whatever schemas match your string) will appear again.

You could create a bookmarklet and save it so that you don't have to open the browser console. If you save this as a bookmark and set this as the URL, it will remove temp tables when you click on it:

`javascript:(()=>{function%20closetemp(ns)%7B%0A%09ns.forEach(n%3D%3E%7B%0A%20%20%20%20if(n._metadata.data._type%20%3D%3D%20'coll-schema')%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20n._children.forEach(s%3D%3E%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if(s._fileName.indexOf('_temp_')!%3D-1)%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20pgAdmin.Browser.tree.remove(s)%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D)%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20if(n._children!%3Dnull)%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%09closetemp(n._children)%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%7D)%0A%7D%0Aclosetemp(pgAdmin.Browser.tree.children())})()`